# Only allow certain type of sequence in antlr grammar

Tags: compiler-construction, grammar, antlr4

I have this exercise but unsure how to solve it. 
I've tried written some code to future improve it for the problem in the grammar.g4 ex.

```
string32
: ID
{
    final String id = $ID.text;
    if ((id.length() > 32))
        throw new RecognitionException();
}
;

ID    : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z')+
;
```

Is it possible you can guide me how to solve it?

[image: Excercise question]

Comment: You should start by answering the question of whether the language is context-free. If not, what will you do? The code you show is not entirely irrelevant to the solution but where does the limit come from? And is it sufficient to just check that the ID is not too long? What if it is too short?